# Any one can create a bag file for me?

Tags: ros, bagfile, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

To work on my thesis I need a bag file from a PR2 (or similar differential wheeled robot) sensors, and follows a simple closed path, like a square or a triangle.

Topic that I need are:

```
/camera/rgb/image_rect 
/camera/rgb/camera_info 
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect 
/camera/depth_registered/camera_info 
/odom 
/imu 
/tf 
/scan
```

Can anyone do me this favor and prepare such bag file?

One more thing, there most be walls or something around the path to create a map with using `gmapping`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/160521/any-one-can-create-a-bag-file-for-me?/) by [maysamsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4226/maysamsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2014-05-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2014-05-04**:
Have you tried KITTI dataset?http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/ http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a number of differential drive robots with lasers available here: http://fergy.me/slam/ although the robots typically drove quite a long way. For some of the bag files, there are also ground truth maps in the form of .pgm files.

EDIT: just noticed this in another question I answered: MIT has also posted bagfiles acquired on a PR2: http://projects.csail.mit.edu/stata/d... These include a lot more than just laser data.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maysamsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4226/maysamsh/) on 2014-05-04**:
It seems none of them have camera related topics, they are quite small files to have video data.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-05-05**:
Yes that is right -- I missed the list of topics you were looking for, and honed in on the "gmapping" and map building part. Sorry for the noise.

**Comment by [maysamsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4226/maysamsh/) on 2014-06-11**:
Finally I had to use MIT dataset.